# Как получить данные из формы средствами jquery, ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

Есть джанговская форма

```
<div class="field inline" id='lot'>
    <label for="{{ form.lot_cost.id_for_label }}" class="subhead">Цена единицы:</label>
    {{ form.lot_cost }}
    {{ form.lot_currency }}
</div>
```

Нужно вытащить из неё значение `{{ form.lot_currency }}` и передать его во второй `span` вместо `usd`

```
<div class="field inline" id="specially">
    <label for="specially" class="subhead">Специальная цена от</label>
    <span>кг</span>
    <span>usd</span>
</div>
```

На странице Джанго рендерит такой шаблон 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
**P.S.** `{{ form.lot_currency }}` является выпадающим селектом, так что нужно выбирать значения по клику и *автоматически*, используя ajax, их подставлять во второй span.

**forms.py**

```
'lot_currency': forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'select2',
                    'style': 'width: 100px'
                }
            ),
```

Это, вроде, несложно. Но с jquery я не знаком(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var firstOption = $('#id_lot_currency option').first();
var lastSpan = $('#specially span').last();
$('#id_lot_currency').change(function(event) {
    var value = $(this).val();
    var label = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
    if (value !== firstOption.val())
        lastSpan.text(label);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="field inline" id='lot'>
    <label for="{{ form.lot_cost.id_for_label }}" class="subhead">Цена единицы:</label>
    <select id="id_lot_currency" name="lot_currency">
        <option selected>---</option>
        <option value="1">USD</option>
        <option value="2">EUR</option>
        <option value="3">RUR</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="field inline" id="specially">
    <label for="specially" class="subhead">Специальная цена от</label>
    <span>кг</span>
    <span>usd</span>
</div>
```

Comment: не работает... можете создать чат, чтобы не засорять комментарии?

Comment: Вы нажимаете кнопку "Выполнить код" и мой пример не работает?

Comment: Ваш код работает здесь. У меня на живом коде не работает(

Comment: В консоли ошибки есть?

Comment: в консоле ввобще пусто..

Comment: https://imgur.com/yyq6JgX

Comment: Возможно, это связано с тем, что Джанго рендерит немного отличительный шаблон от Вашего.

Comment: В приложенном вами скрине есть `select` с идентификатором `id_lot_currency`. Если есть и  `div` с идентификатором `specially` и хоть одним дочерним `span`, то работать должно.

Comment: Проверяйте, что скрипт загружается и что обработчик `change` назначается.